# How to reference a Type in another Type in object relational Database SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i have this sql code , i want to reference types in another type , like below referencing PaymentType and CustomerType in OrderType and scoping them in the OrderTable. But i am getting this error `Errors: TYPE ORDERTYPE
Line/Col: 0/0 PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
Line/Col: 7/17 PLS-00588: unqualified instance attribute references allowed only in member methods

Errors: TYPE PICKUPORDER
Line/Col: 0/0 PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
Line/Col: 1/24 PLS-00905: object SQL_LIIYHAAYFONIVNSUTWPPQXPDP.ORDERTYPE is invalid

Errors: TYPE DELIVERYORDER
Line/Col: 0/0 PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
Line/Col: 1/26 PLS-00905: object SQL_LIIYHAAYFONIVNSUTWPPQXPDP.ORDERTYPE is invalid`

I thought it was due to subtypes of PaymentType and subtypes of CustomerType during inheritance, i removed the subtypes and tried it , am still facing the same issue.

```
CREATE TYPE AddressType AS OBJECT ( 
    street VARCHAR2(50), 
    city VARCHAR2(50), 
    plot NUMBER 
); 
/

CREATE TYPE PaymentType AS OBJECT ( 
    paymentID NUMBER, 
    totalAmount NUMBER,
    paymentMethod VARCHAR2(20)
);
/


CREATE TYPE CustomerType AS OBJECT ( 
    customerID NUMBER, 
    firstName VARCHAR2(50), 
    lastName VARCHAR2(50), 
    address AddressType,
    typeOfCustomer VARCHAR2(20),
    payment REF PaymentType,
    MEMBER FUNCTION discount RETURN NUMBER
); 
/

CREATE TYPE DeliveryDriverType AS OBJECT ( 
    driverID NUMBER, 
    firstName VARCHAR2(50), 
    lastName VARCHAR2(50)
) 
/

CREATE TYPE OrderType AS OBJECT ( 
    orderID NUMBER, 
    orderedFoodItems VARCHAR2(200), 
    estimatedPreparationTime NUMBER, 
    paymentType VARCHAR2(50), 
    orderPlacementTime DATE,
    payment REF PaymentType,
    customer REF CustomerType,
    deliveryDriver REF DeliveryDriverType,
    MEMBER FUNCTION orderTotal RETURN NUMBER 
) NOT FINAL; 
/

CREATE TYPE pickupOrder UNDER OrderType ( 
    pickUpTime TIMESTAMP, 
    OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION orderTotal RETURN NUMBER 
); 
/

CREATE TYPE deliveryOrder UNDER OrderType ( 
    estimatedDeliveryTime TIMESTAMP, 
    OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION orderTotal RETURN NUMBER 
); 
/

CREATE TABLE payment OF PaymentType ( 
    paymentID PRIMARY KEY 
);

CREATE TABLE customer OF CustomerType ( 
    customerID PRIMARY KEY 
    payment SCOPE IS payment WITH ROWID 
);

CREATE TABLE deliveryDriver OF DeliveryDriverType ( 
    driverID PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE orderTable OF OrderType ( 
    orderID PRIMARY KEY,
    payment SCOPE IS payment WITH ROWID,
    customer SCOPE IS customer WITH ROWID,
    deliveryDriver SCOPE IS deliveryDriver WITH ROWID
    
);
```

Comment: are you sure this is for oracle https://dbfiddle.uk/K0dNQGFG

Comment: @nbk Am new to this so i learnt it this way , so i will say yes. If am wrong please correct me

Comment: there are all member function missing as you see in the fiddle

Comment: @nbk sorry my bad , i omitted them , especially OrderType member functions since they were giving errors too but the errors were due to the parent being invalid , so there is no how the subtypes will work.

Comment: it is very hard to debug something that e know nothing about, you can use the fiddle and add there the functions, and so we can help you

Comment: @nbk okay let me add the functions to the same link you shared

Comment: @nbk I added them to same link you shared, you can check them. Thanks

Comment: @jayCoder You need to run the fiddle and share the link for the updated fiddle with us. Make sure it runs with as few errors as possible.

Comment: @MT0 Okay great, here it is https://dbfiddle.uk/Tc61Qfdw

Comment: @jayCoder - the problem is still the name clash; and you need to split the last two type body statements into separate blocks in the fiddle - [this now compiles](https://dbfiddle.uk/em6ZiRLl).

Comment: @AlexPoole your suggestion solved the issue,Thank you so much. But like i stated there still lies an issue PaymentType had subtypes being bankingcard and cash and customer had subtypes being new customer and regular customer it gave the same error  i had to remove the subtypes

Comment: @AlexPoole updated fiddle is here ,   https://dbfiddle.uk/YCboe4lt

Comment: That fiddle still has the name clash; but the subtypes are getting a different error, because you haven't made the supertypes `NOT FINAL`. If you do that and fix typos [then it compiles](https://dbfiddle.uk/cQixLym3). You aren't using the subtypes yet though; but [it compiles if you do](https://dbfiddle.uk/BoEu30DC). If you still have a problem then ask a new question with a [mre].

Comment: @AlexPoole Okay thank you , let me work on that , my idea was to reference paymentType which has subtypes like in fiddle and customer in orderType and make them valid in the table orderTable. Sorry  this had to be so long . I havent slept well because of this

Comment: I imagine you want to keep those attributes as the not-final parent types in the other object/table definitions. Then you can store either subtype - which is kind of the point.

Comment: @AlexPoole i tried to address the issues and implement the member functions , https://dbfiddle.uk/rDVainHC

Comment: As I said before, in db<>fiddle each statement/block has to be in its own text area; and you can use `select * from user errors` to see what PL/SQL errors you are getting. With the blocks split properly and two trailing commas removed, again, [that compiles](https://dbfiddle.uk/1vFCgp2i). If you still have a problem then ask a new question with a [mre].

Comment: @AlexPoole Quick update, i managed to correct the entire code including inheritance parts. Thank you all for your help .God Bless you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't at all obvious from the error message, but you are getting the ORA-00588 error because of a name clash.

You are defining your table with a column `paymentType`, which has the same name as your object type:

```
CREATE TYPE OrderType AS OBJECT ( 
    orderID NUMBER, 
    orderedFoodItems VARCHAR2(200), 
    estimatedPreparationTime NUMBER, 
    paymentType VARCHAR2(50), 
----^^^^^^^^^^^
    orderPlacementTime DATE,
    payment REF PaymentType,
----------------^^^^^^^^^^^
    customer REF CustomerType,
    deliveryDriver REF DeliveryDriverType,
    MEMBER FUNCTION orderTotal RETURN NUMBER 
) NOT FINAL;
```

If you change the name of the column to something else then it will compile, e.g.:

```
CREATE TYPE OrderType AS OBJECT ( 
    orderID NUMBER, 
    orderedFoodItems VARCHAR2(200), 
    estimatedPreparationTime NUMBER, 
    paymentTypeStr VARCHAR2(50), 
    orderPlacementTime DATE,
    payment REF PaymentType,
    customer REF CustomerType,
    deliveryDriver REF DeliveryDriverType,
    MEMBER FUNCTION orderTotal RETURN NUMBER 
) NOT FINAL;
```

You also have an error in the `customer` table, which is missing a comma:

```
CREATE TABLE customer OF CustomerType ( 
    customerID PRIMARY KEY, 
    payment SCOPE IS payment WITH ROWID 
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3M0VUJpS)

If you want to subtypes `PaymentType` and `CustomerType` then you have to define those as `NOT FINAL` - as in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BoEu30DC) from comments.

Comment: Thank you for your response , let me try your suggestion

Comment: Wow it worked , i didnt see this ,i really missed this because i havent been sleeping because of this , thinking i can solve it.